# Resources to prepare for safety-critical software (medical) interview?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, safety

Has anyone found interview preparation resources specific to safety-critical design? In this case for medical applications?

I have an interview coming up and it's clear from their communication that they will make it technical within the scope of safety-critical.

I thought about reviewing the MISRA-C standards but other then that can't really think of nothing else.

Previous experience in automotive just for context.

Comment: There might be a useful question in here but as written this doesn't seem like a good fit for the site as it's specific to the position you're interviewing for while potential answers can't hope to be exhaustive or particularly useful for others unless they're in the exact same situation. I'm flagging to close this as [an advice question](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2695#2695).

Comment: Have a look at ISO 9001, ISO 27001. Read up on "Failure Mode and Effects Analysis" and then mention it once, show that you link it to "Risk Assessment" and you can just say "Risk assessment" for the rest of the interview. This is not about medical software development, it's about critical systems software development. Show that you have a good understanding of risk management and project management taking risk management into account, and the rest is just standard Quality Assurance, performed to a stringent level.

Comment: Medical device regulations are NOT "company specific". This is a very large technology sector and answers to this question have wide applicability. Please don't be so trigger happy to close questions for superficial reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself have gone through an interview process to a medical oriented company too. I was not a senior position candidate at all - I had knowledge of the topics from my academical research/classes but other than that my experience was leaning more into general software development.

What I did was researching their white papers/published books on topics they may ask during the interviews. Not only I've learned many things along the way, but it also helped me during the dialogue with them because I could refer to some of their findings, which assured them that I did my homework. It's okay if you make a mistake during interview and it's okay to admit it. Just don't make stuff up if you get lost...

One thing you could also do is asking your HR contact for advice. Some big companies even give out some materials or pointers to where to get them from.

Comment: I think the white papers aspect is a really good point. In my case in particular they are consultants so they don't have any output i assume because of NDAs with clients but it's a good strategy in general. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

The best preparation for a technical interview is to actually possess the necessary technical knowledge and experience. Trying to cheat your way through it by just trying to learn what you need for the interview is not going to end well. In the best case, the interviewer asks questions you can not find in the book and realizes you are a phony. But in the worst case you will get a job you are underqualified for and cause lots of damage to the company, by extension to your career and in this special case even endanger lifes.

So the question you *should* be asking is not "how do I learn just enough to pass an interview" but rather "what do I need to learn to become a competent professional". And this is a question you should ask to a specialized audience and not a general audience like workplace stackexchange.

Comment: I didn't have the impression that the OP is trying to cheat anything. I believe the question is asking for serious advice on learning materials, no shortcuts or anything.

Comment: I agree that Phillipp assumed an ill intention that is not there. I am qualified otherwise I would have been asked for an interview (I didn't apply for the position I was contacted). My question is in preparation for context specific (medical) safety-critical software. It's naive to consider there is no need for interview-specific preparation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's about quality assurance: proving that the design implements the requirements, proving that the code implements the design, proving that the tests are testing, etc.

I think it's not easy to pretend to have experience with medical software QA, but you can (should) at least brush up on (or review or be prepared to talk about in an interview) your previous experience of software QA in general.